# EditText won't follow style for 4.2 Jelly Bean (Holo Light)

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple view to sign up for an account. The Text fields look terrible and won't follow the a standard style. (I would like to use Holo.) How do you make the EditText look either like the Holo style or look like the indented into the page style? I know about 9-patch and gradients but is there a way to keep the style consistent with other apps on the version of android?

**The EditText**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".SingUp"
 tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
 android:background="@drawable/homebackground"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"> 


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/enteredname"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12pt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@layout/rounded_style" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**rounded_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

Also how do you make the cursor start with a little space before left edge?

Comment: background="@layout/..." ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you have changed the background of the EditText to **"rounded_style"**, that's why it might not be working as you would want it to.

Generally, an EditText should have **3-4 different images for different states** (Normal, focussed, disabled etc). If you have those, it should work fine.

Please share your code snippets and some images of the current implementation.